# SQL Login Problem in asp

Tags: sql-server, asp-classic, ado

> Error Type:
>   Microsoft OLE DB Provider
>   for SQL Server (0x80040E4D)
>   Login failed for user 'BUILTIN\Users'.
>   /asptest/login.asp, line 9

Can any one tell me why this appear to me when ever i try to open my asp page. i m able to get access using this user name. "BUILTIN\Users" in SQL Server Visual maangement studio....
Do tell me the solution if any one have

Comment: What is the connection string you are using?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you are missing Trusted_Connection=yes in your connection string for your asp page.